# How can I use power query to join financial data from two months with varying customers?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I would like to join several months worth of customer invoicing data with customers in one column. The problem is... some months, certain customers may not make a purchase at all. I would like to combine the months and just show a 0 or null for that month when joined.

I have simplified the data in this to protect customers' privacy.

| customer | feb 23 |
| --- | --- |
| customer 1 | $1000 |
| customer 2 | $2000 |
| customer 4 | $4000 |

| customer | mar 23 |
| --- | --- |
| customer 1 | $1000 |
| customer 3 | $3000 |
| customer 5 | $5000 |

What I would expect this to return by FULL JOINING queries:

| customer | feb 23 | mar 23 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| customer 1 | $1000 | $1000 |
| customer 2 | $2000 | $0 |
| customer 3 | $0 | $3000 |
| customer 4 | $4000 | $0 |
| customer 5 | $0 | $5000 |

What I actually get is this:

| customer | feb 23 | mar 23 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| customer 1 | $1000 | $1000 |
| customer 2 | $2000 | $0 |
| customer 4 | $4000 | $0 |
| null | $0 | $4000 |
| null | $0 | $5000 |

Is there a way to get PQ to fully combine the customer column without leaving the nonmatching rows out? Full joining doesn't seem to do the trick like I would expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Combine all the tables
- Unpivot all columns except the `customer` column
- Pivot on the month/yr column with no aggregation

So given:
[image]

and this code:

```
let

//Read in all the tables
//Change next lines to reflect actual data sources
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Feb_2023"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"customer", type text}, {"23-Feb", Currency.Type}}),

    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Mar_2023"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type 1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,{{"customer", type text}, {"23-Mar", Currency.Type}}),

//Append all the tables
    Append = Table.Combine({#"Changed Type",#"Changed Type 1"}),

//Unpivot all except the customer column
    UnPivot = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Append,{"customer"}, "Month/Yr", "Amount"),

//Then Pivot on Month/Yr with no aggregation
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(UnPivot, List.Distinct(UnPivot[#"Month/Yr"]), "Month/Yr", "Amount")

in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

will result in your desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are using the first table's (feb 23) `customer` column, which is indeed null for those two lines.

You want to use something like `table1.customer ?? table2.customer`, which will return the customer from the first table if it exists, or the second table if it is null.

Answer (score 0):

Unpivot each table on `customer` column:

```
= Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"customer"}, "Month", "Value")
```

Then Append the two (not merge)

```
= Table.Combine({Table1, Table2})
```

Finally, if you really want to, you can then pivot the result on the `Month`:

```
= Table.Pivot(Source, List.Distinct(Source[Month]), "Month", "Value")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach..

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Feb_23"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"customer", type text}, {"23-Feb", Int64.Type}}),
#"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({#"Changed Type", Mar_23}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Appended Query", {"customer"}, {{"Feb_23", each List.Sum([#"23-Feb"]), type nullable number}, {"Mar_23", each List.Sum([#"23-Mar"]), type nullable number}}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows",{{"customer", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Sorted Rows",null,0,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Feb_23", "Mar_23"}) in
#"Replaced Value"
```

[image: result]